# Unable to send email from Office 365 using c# SmtpClient

Tags: c#, office365, smtpclient

Trying to send email from my winforms app in c# using SmtpClient. Going by this MS [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fHow-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4#option2) it should work. I have searched many forums etc and have not found any solutions to this. The error message seems to suggest that client is not authenticated. The password is correct I have logged in as this user withthe password and its fine. 2FA is on but htis should not get in the way should it?

Things I have checked are in place

1. Enable SSl
2. From email and user email is the same
3. Port 587
4. I have this account in outlook and it sends just fine
5. Firewall is not blocking this port. I have other code using this exact same code with a non O365 host and it works just fine

**Code**

```
            var userName = "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "password";
            var msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("user@gmail.com"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
            msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
            msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var client = new SmtpClient{
                Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password),
                Port = 587,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            client.Send(msg);
```

**Exception**

- The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
  authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
  authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

**MAIL KIT IMPLEMENTATION** (suggestion of vasily.sib)

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test User", "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Gmail User", "testuser@gmail.com"));
        message.Subject = "test";

        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = @"test"
        };

        var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("imap.log"));


        // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

        client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto); //this is fine and it connects

        var clientAuthenticationMechanisms = client.AuthenticationMechanisms;
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate("user@domain.onmicrosoft.com", "password"); // this is where it fails with Authentication Failure

        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
```

**MAIL KIT LOG OUTPUT**

```
Connected to smtp://smtp.office365.com:587/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 SYCP282CA0015.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 25 Nov 2019 04:49:36 +0000
C: EHLO [192.168.2.50]
S: 250-SYCP282CA0015.outlook.office365.com Hello [58.6.92.82]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
C: EHLO [192.168.2.50]
S: 250-SYCP282CA0015.outlook.office365.com Hello [58.6.92.82]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: AUTH LOGIN
REMOVED BASE64 DATA (password, login)
S: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SYCP282CA0015.AUSP282.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

Comment: Microsoft doesn't recommend to use [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) (see remarks section). Try MailKit instead.

Comment: @vasily.sib ...tried that but it does not work. Unable to Authenticate..I tried the email and password again and it works fine but in code it does not authenticate..Would 2FA be stopping it?

Comment: are you running your code under any proxy server like inside corporate network?

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR no. When I run it using MailKit I concect just fine to "smtp.office365.com" on port 587 but when I attempt to Authenticate it fails..only thing I can think of is the username and password but they are both fine as I can login to portal.office.com with these and see the inbox there

Answer (score 4):

Solved. It was the 2FA that was stopping it from happening. Turned it off and it worked

Comment: You don't have to turn it off, you can configure an App password for your application.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12409/microsoft-account-app-passwords-and-two-step-verification#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Security%20basics,and%20appears%20on%20your%20screen.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today.
Office365 also expects TLS connection.
Therefore, you should add the following code to your codes

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Expect100Continue  was not needed in my case.  But Tls12 fixed my issue.